Cache busting: What encoding is used for the hash part of Angular file names?
In previous versions of angular, hashed file names looked like this:
runtime.59772ce71fd8c096.js
polyfills.efe34593e33fb8e1.js
scripts.109c3e02aa410456.js
main.3645a30dcf6ebeb0.js

They were composed by a name followed by a dot, then 16 characters corresponding to the hexadecimal encoding of the hash, then the extension.
Now they look like this:
styles-GCSEUS35.css
chunk-NLN56U2H.js
polyfills-UCPGG4LZ.js
main-UFPD5ECZ.js

They are composed by a name followed by an hyphen, then the hash encoded in 8 characters, ending with the extension.
They somehow look as base32, but base32 Crockford doesn't include the "U" character.
I just need to know what characters can be included in the hash part of the file.
The reason I need it is cache busting.
If I can figure out in my server code that a file is a hashed Angular file, I can send cache headers to the browser that allows it to cache the file for a long time without revalidation.

Angular now uses esbuild for its compilation, so you should check the documentation to see the process of naming the bundle files to avoid name collision.
Check the asset names section of the documentation. Regarding how this hash is created, its seems that only capital letters and numbers are used.
If that can help, you also have the possibility to disable hashing with the build command. You can use the output-hashing option.

Both links point to the same cli-build documentation. I'm not interested in how to disable hashing file names. I want to take advantage of them to cache busting. But I need to know the encoding or at least the character set used for encoding the hash
